# How to return JSON property (SQL Server)

Tags: json, sql-server

I am trying to select some data that is stored as JSON in SQL Server.

When I run `isjson` on the string, it returns 1.

However, I am unable to parse it.

```
declare @testStr nvarchar(max) = '{"order":{"address":{"shipToAddLine1":"1234 ABC Dr","shipToCityStZip":"Washington, DC 00000"}}}'
select isjson(@testStr)                 -- returns 1
select json_value(@testStr, '$').       -- returns null
select json_value(@testStr, '$.order')  -- returns null
select @testStr                         -- returns entire string
```

How do I select the `order` node from the test string `@testStr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [`JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) because that is not a scalar value, you need to use [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead. An example of a scalar value would be the `shipToAddLine1` field: `select json_value(@testStr, '$.order.address.shipToAddLine1')`.

Using [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the order would be:

```
select json_query(@testStr, '$.order')
```

Result:

> {"address":{"shipToAddLine1":"1234 ABC Dr","shipToCityStZip":"Washington, DC 00000"}}

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, `json_value` wasn't working because the property had child nodes?

Comment: @Matthew - json_value is not working because it expects an scalar value like a single string or number or date etc. If you want a whole node then use `json_query`.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_VALUE()`, `JSON_QUERY()` and `OPENJSON()` to parse the input JSON. It's important to mention the following:

- Function `JSON_QUERY` extracts an object or an array from a `JSON` string. If the value is not an object or an array, the result is `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict` mode.
- Function `JSON_VALUE` extracts a scalar value from a `JSON` string. If the `path` points to not a scalar value, the result is `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict` mode
- When you want to parse `JSON` string and get results as table, use `OPENJSON` table-valued function.

If you need to extract the `order` key you have two options - `JSON_QUERY()` or `OPENJSON()`. The following statement demonstrates how to extract a JSON object (from `$.order` key) and JSON values (from `$.order.address.shipToAddLine1` and `$.order.address.shipToCityStZip` keys):

```
DECLARE @testStr nvarchar(max) = 
N'{
   "order":{
      "address":{
         "shipToAddLine1":"1234 ABC Dr",
         "shipToCityStZip":"Washington, DC 00000"
      }
   }
}'

-- or

SELECT 
   shipToAddLine1 = JSON_VALUE(@testStr, '$.order.address.shipToAddLine1'),
   shipToCityStZip = JSON_VALUE(@testStr, '$.order.address.shipToCityStZip'),
   [order] = JSON_QUERY(@testStr, '$.order')

SELECT shipToAddLine1, shipToCityStZip, [order]
FROM OPENJSON(@testStr) WITH (
   shipToAddLine1 nvarchar(100) '$.order.address.shipToAddLine1',
   shipToCityStZip nvarchar(100) '$.order.address.shipToCityStZip' ,
   [order] nvarchar(max) '$.order' AS JSON
)
```

Result:

```
shipToAddLine1  shipToCityStZip         order
1234 ABC Dr     Washington, DC 00000    {
                                           "address":{
                                              "shipToAddLine1":"1234 ABC Dr",
                                              "shipToCityStZip":"Washington, DC 00000"
                                           }
                                        }
```